# java Object evading cursor

Tags: java, cursor, awt, mouse-listeners

I'm working on something and hit a brick wall.  My program is supposed to make a circle which evades the cursor.  I have it almost finished but I just need help with the if statement at the bottom.  How would I properly format it so I don't keep getting the error?

```
private void setCircle(MouseEvent s) {

    int getx = s.getX();int gety = s.getY();

    Random random = new Random();

    randomX = random.nextInt(700 - 51) + 51;
    randomY = random.nextInt(700 - 51) + 51;


    setX(randomX); setY(randomY);


    if((getx)>x)&&(getx)<(x+80))||((getx)>x)&&(getx)>(x-80))&&((y<gety)&&(gety<(y+80))||((gety)>y)&&(gety)>(y-80)){

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error? Rule number 1: Always include the exact error message! (as it contains valuable information on what is causing it...)

Comment: `if((getx)>x)...` here the parenthesis of the `if` is already closed...

Comment: Please create temporary variables to store long calculations like this. The nested parenthesis are terrible. One marker of good code is code you can read and understand easily in 6 months.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:ElusiveBall [line: 68] - 
  setCircle(MouseEvent)
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error on token "&&", invalid (
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - Syntax error on token "&&", invalid AssignmentOperator
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

Comment: For one thing, there is no requirement to fit the entire condition in one line. Split it to logical parts.

Comment: Also, parens should be used only where they are required for correct operation (either because the compiler needs them, e.g. for an if statement, or because they're acting as the precedence operator) or where they improve readability.  The parens around gety in `((gety)>y)` do none of these things, and that clause would be better written as `(gety>y)`.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies here:

```
if((getx)>x)&&...
  ^        ^
```

By the time the compiler parses the 2nd end-paren, it thinks that the marked parentheses enclose the entire if-statement. To fix this, work on re-organizing the parentheses (I would follow kiheru's comment and split up your conditions).

To start off, you're checking if `getx` and `gety` are within a certain range. For instance, you can write:

```
boolean getxInBounds = getx > x && getx < (x+80);
```

and use that variable in your if-statement.